# Явное приведение типов в C++

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь получить в ответе переменную `t2` не как тип `int`, а как `float`. Т.е. сейчас при вводе числа `457` у меня `number two = 5`, а я хочу получить `5.7`. Код уже с примером, как я пытаюсь сделать, но всё равно выводит без десятых. Что я делаю не так?

```
int e, n;
float s, t2;
cout << "vvedite n\n";
cin >> n;
s = float(n) / 100 ;        // первая цифра
t2 = float ((n / 10) % 10); // вторая цифра
e = n % 10;                 // третья цифра
cout << "number one =   " << float(s) << endl;
cout << "number two =   " << float(t2) << endl;
cout << "number fri =   " << e << endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из целого числа вы никогда не получите с помощью приведения вещественное с ненулевой дробной частью. Ей просто неоткуда там взяться. Если нужно получить хвост без старшего разряда, то самый простой вариант — просто выполнить вычитание целой части, связанной со старшим разрядом, перед делением:

```
int n = 457;
s = n / 100.0;  // 4.57
t2 = (n - static_cast<int>(s) * 100) / 10.0; // 5.7
e = n % 10; // 7
```

При желании можно обернуть в цикл, чтобы работать не только с трехразрядными числами.

Answer (score 2):

У вас переменная t2 и так является типом float. Операция "модуль" (%) не используется с типами с плавающей запятой. Выход - пользоваться функцией **fmod** из стандартной библиотеки. К тому же, чтобы получить 5.7 нужно несколько иначе считать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  int e, n;
  float s, t2, t2fmod;

  cout << "vvedite n  \n";
  cin >> n;

  s = n / 100 ;
  t2 = (n % 100) / 10.0; // (int) / (float) = (float); или static_cast<float>(10) -- глупо
  // или
  t2fmod = fmod(n, 100) / 10; // (float) / (int) = (float);
  e = n % 10;

  cout << "number one  =   " << s << endl;
  cout << "number two =   " << fixed << setprecision(1) << t2 << "(" << t2fmod << ")" << endl;
  cout << "number three =   " << e << endl;  
}
```

Явные приведения типов в стиле Си (`(type)variable`) нежелательны в C++. Лучше пользоваться операциями *_cast.